# Is there a way to insert multiple SQL files to mysql (with password) using a shell script?

Tags: mysql, sql, shell, makefile

I just want to ask if it's possible to make a Makefile/script that will let me enter my MySQL password one time only and then insert all of my SQL files into the database. I currently have something like this on my Makefile.

```
mysql -u root -p < ./sqlfile1.sql
mysql -u root -p < ./sqlfile2.sql
...
mysql -u root -p < ./sqlfile34.sql
```

It's just really exhausting for me to enter the password for every SQL file every time.

What I'm hoping I can do is when I run the command, the prompt will ask me for a password once only, and then it will automatically enter the password for every SQL file.

---

### UPDATE

I'm trying to make this work, but I'm faced with this warning:

> [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

...followed by this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Here is my code below (as per Ron's [https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291328/ron] solution):

```
#!/bin/bash

db_alpha:

    read mypass
    make db_build
    make db_dummy

db_build:
    mysql -u root -p$mypass < ./backend/database/functions.sql
    make db_procedures 
    mysql -u root -p$mypass < ./backend/database/triggers.sql

db_dummy:
    mysql -u root -p$mypass < ./backend/database/dummy/dummy_user.sql 

db_procedures:
    mysql -u root -p$mypass < ./backend/database/procedures/procedure_user.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo enter your pass:
read mypass
for z in  ./sqlfile1.sql ./sqlfile2.sql ./sqlfile2.sql; do
  echo importing file: $z
  mysql -u root -p$mypass -D databasename < "$z"
done
```

### Update:

depending no how your .sql files are structured, you might need to specify the `-D databasename` in your command.
Please check the updated script. It works for me.

You might also need to specify `-h 127.0.0.1` in that same line, to specify the host.

Since you are running the CLI mysql client and providing a password in clear text, you will be seeing a warning:

> [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
> This is not an error, so it can be ignored.

And finally you, of course, need to be using the proper credentials.

Comment: Hi Ron! I'm encountering an 'end of file unexpected' syntax error from the for loop so I temporarily used the echo & read commands and then duplicated this command: ( mysql -u root -p"$mypass" < ./sqlfile1.sql ) in rows. But now, mysql gave me a "[Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure." message, followed by an ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. Do you know how to fix it? :)

Comment: Show the exact script you are using

Comment: Hey Ron! I'm sorry if it took me a while to reply. I edited my post and included the Makefile I'm currently working on. :)

Comment: If your password contains any special characters add `quotes` like:  -p"$mypass" , if that does not work, then you either do not have a password for user `root` on localhost or the password you are using is simply wrong.. You can also add in your question the output of mysql command: `show grants for 'root'@'localhost';`